# How can I forcibly restart/reload a Playback device programatically in Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, device-driver

By forcibly I mean even when some audio applications are using it.

By reload I mean the kind of thing that happens after the shared mode sample rate of the speaker is changed in the advanced tab of Speaker Properties. Any audio applications stop immediately.

Is it possible to do such a restart programatically? (Or even for that matter change the shared mode sampling rate programmatically via any Interface the SDK exposes)

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically restart the "Windows Audio Service" which may do the trick.